# Pivoted pandas dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

```
df
#     col3 2000 5000 7500 10000 12000 15000 20000 30000
#col1 col2                              
#  22   0   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN
#       1   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN
#  24   0     1  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN   NaN
#       1     1  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN
#  26   0   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN   NaN
#       1   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN   NaN
#  29   0     1  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
#  31   1   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

and I need to first map each record  as follows (pseudo code) `if df.ix[row,col] == 1: df.ix[row,col] = col`.

I then want to store the mapped records in a list, ignoring NaN values, e.g. something like

```
[ ('col2_0' , 20000), ('col2_1' , 20000),
  ('col2_0' , 2000), ('col2_1', 2000),
  ('col2_0' , 15000), ('cols_1' , 20000),
  ('col2_0' , 15000), ('col2_1' , 15000),
  ('col2_0' , 2000), ('col2_1' , 2000),
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might take the [tour] and visit the [help] because your question lacks a few quality attributes we expect from posts. In the links you find guidance that helps you how to improve your question by giving it an [edit].

Comment: I edited the post to make it somewhat more clear. You might consider accepting it so you can receive some help. Most importantly, you should know that a dict cannot be as you described above (having duplicate keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you on your way. Assume you have a dataframe

```
d
#           2000  3000
#col1 col2            
#0    0        1     1
#1    0        1     1
#     1        1   NaN
#2    0        1     1
#     1        1   NaN
#3    0      NaN     1
#     1        1   NaN
```

Next you want to reset the index

```
d_flat = d.reset_index()
#   col1  col2  2000  3000
#0     0     0     1     1
#1     1     0     1     1
#2     1     1     1   NaN
#3     2     0     1     1
#4     2     1     1   NaN
#5     3     0   NaN     1
#6     3     1     1   NaN
```

Now, you can map column 2:

```
d_flat.col2 = d_flat.col2.map(lambda x: 'col2_%d'%x)

#d_flad.col2
#0    col2_0
#1    col2_0
#2    col2_1
#3    col2_0
#4    col2_1
#5    col2_0
#6    col2_1
#Name: col2, dtype: object
```

the next step you want to create a list of dictionaries for each row. Do the following

```
mycols = ['2000', '3000']
d_dict = d_flat[mycols].to_dict(orient='records')
#[{'2000': 1.0, '3000': 1.0},
# {'2000': 1.0, '3000': 1.0},
# {'2000': 1.0, '3000': nan},
# {'2000': 1.0, '3000': 1.0},
# {'2000': 1.0, '3000': nan},
# {'2000': nan, '3000': 1.0},
# {'2000': 1.0, '3000': nan}]
```

The `orient='records'` option stores each entry separate, so you can have duplicate entries (this is why there is a list of dicts as opposed to a single dict).

Next comes the fun part. You want to carefully filter out the nan values, which you can do in a comprehension.

```
from itertools import izip

mylist = [(col,key)  
          for col,records in izip( d_flat.col2, d_dict) 
          for key,val in records.iteritems() 
          if not pandas.np.isnan(val)]
#[('col2_0', '2000'),
# ('col2_0', '3000'),
# ('col2_0', '2000'),
# ('col2_0', '3000'),
# ('col2_1', '2000'),
# ('col2_0', '2000'),
# ('col2_0', '3000'),
# ('col2_1', '2000'),
# ('col2_0', '3000'),
# ('col2_1', '2000')]
```